# New Account Contact relationship (LWC)

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, slds

I am building a custom LWC and on that component I have to give users ability to add a new indirect relationship among other things.

I wonder, if there is a way to open this popup window from a custom LWC or should I hardcode this form instead? If so, please give some guidelines, it's from my test case to get an internship as a junior salesforce developer, any help will be much appreciated!
[image: con]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do what I needed with

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'AccountContactRelation',
            actionName: 'new'
        },
    });
```

though with this method there is no way to prepopulate the form with default values and I still don't know how to override the 'aftersave' action, to prevent the page redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can use force:CreateRecord event on user click which will open the ACR page

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation